# Shortcuting Doctrine Code

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is there is any way to Shortcut this Code

```
 $questions = $this->getdoctrine()->getrepository('AppBundle:TicketQuestions')->find($id = 1);
 $question1 = $questions->getQuestions();
 $option1   = $questions->getOption1();
 $option2   = $questions->getOption2();
 $option3   = $questions->getOption3();
```

Because i want to use more than 20 times.

i use this code to get some questions and options from database for a Ticket system and i hope there is a way to not write a very long code for that.

Comment: Why not put that logic in a function that returns an object the way you want, and call that functions?

Comment: Agree with @Dimitri. Write a function in your controller that returns all of these options in an array, then you can call that function from your code, something like `$options = $questions->getOptions();`.

Comment: Thank you guys, you gaved me a Hint to solve my Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks any way guys, i solved it like this -> i wrote new function

```
public function callQuestions($id){
     $questions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:TicketQuestions')->find($id);
     $question = $questions->getQuestions();
     $option1   = $questions->getOption1();
     $option2   = $questions->getOption2();
     $option3   = $questions->getOption3();
     return array($question,$option1,$option2,$option3);
}
```

and now i can call it easily like this:

```
$firstQuestion = TicketsController::callQuestions(1);
```

i will try also to make it shorter but this one works good now.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your Entities. For example, do you have 20 hardcoded "options" in your "Questions" entity?

If you were to use something like an array of options, you could just use a foreach loop and get all those options. But, that also has some foundation in what your data model looks like.

If you want to use an underlying datastructure (such as an array or Doctrine ArrayCollection) you'll first have to structure your database and data scheme with the correct architecture.

This is a much deeper question than can you just write a shortcut, I don't think your underlying data and architecture are implemented correctly to use data structures (array, ArrayCollections).

Comment: Very correct, still not an answer and better posted as a comment